# I can't add input() in python list

Tags: python

```
`i = 0
while i < 5
    i=i+1
    li = []
    li.insert(i,input('>>>'))
print(li)`
```

**When I run this program. It only print last input by me.
Help please**.
  I want add all input in one by one...

Comment: Of course, you are creating a new list every iteration

Comment: `li = []` inside the loop clears whatever `li` was storing earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
li = []
i = 0
while i < 5:
    i=i+1    
    li.insert(i,input('>>>'))
print(li)
```

And if you want to store numbers as integer, try this:

```
li = []
i = 0
while i < 5:
    i=i+1    
    li.insert(i,int(input('>>>')))
print(li)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reset your list to an empty list `[]` on each loop.

Rather than controlling your index yourself, you can use a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Also, use `append` to append an item to your list.

So, your code could become:

```
li = []
for i in range(5):
    li.append(input('>>>'))

print(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension for syntactic sugar. Also yeah to reiterate what others have said above, you reset the list on every iteration. Two, input() is a function that returns raw input(usually interpreted as string) so you need to either control its type return or use Regex to ensure you pull only specific answers(really constraining inputs is good practice). Finally when you iterate over a segment it could be easier to do so as a generator function for memory purposes- look into yield and generative functions.

```
newList = [int(input(‘>>>’)) for x in range(1,5)]
```

Print(newList)

See a single line could create the list you expected